# How to use OptionMenu on Toolbar which is in a Fragment view?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my `Fragment` I want use `Toolbar` - no in `Activity`. How can I use OptionMenu at this `Toolbar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_menu);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) { 
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    //Do your magic
                }                    
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I find solution for me:

I create menu file (xml) and in my fragment method added this lines:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.inventory_list_fragment_menu);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
         return false;
     }
 });
```

It's work for me, thank you.